# How to get the current module/controller/action from a view script in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: view, module, controller, action, zend-framework2

Is it possible to get the current module/controller/action name from a view script? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve it in your controller using the MvcEvent object and then assign it to the ViewModel so you can retrieve it in the view:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   return new ViewModel(
            array(
                'controller' => $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller'),
                'action' => $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action')
            )
        );
}
```

The module name is a bit trickier, but you could for instance get it using the **NAMESPACE** or just parse it from the controller name.

If you want to use this in multiple views then it's probably better to create and register your own view-helper.