# ZF2 get current module from view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I'm trying to get active module name from my custom View Helper.
I could get the correct active module from phtml file like:

```
$module = explode("\\" ,__CLASS__);
$module = end($module);
```

But if i use it in my view helper ofcourse i get path to my helper class.
So how can i get it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current module/controller/action from a view script in Zend Framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960987/how-to-get-the-current-module-controller-action-from-a-view-script-in-zend-frame)

Comment: not duplicate. I need to get module name from my custom view helper __invoke() method. There's only described how to get it from Controller.

Comment: there is no module in zf2 application